# how to compare two cell fields and validate one condition in a devextreme datagrid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, devextreme

My goal is to compare the column `Inicio` and `Finalizacion`, but I don't know how to make a reference of `Inicio` to compare Finalizacion.
I want to do something like this:

```
<CompareRule  comparisonType={("Inicio", ">")}>
```

I tried, but it did not work. This is my code:

```
        <DataGrid
          dataSource={rows_data}
          keyExpr="ID"
          showBorders={true}
          columnAutoWidth={true}
        >
          <Scrolling mode="virtual" />
          <Paging enabled={false} />
          <Editing
            mode="batch"
            allowUpdating={true}
            allowAdding={true}
            allowDeleting={true}
            selectTextOnEditStart={this.state.selectTextOnEditStart}
            startEditAction={this.state.startEditAction}
          >
            <Texts
              deleteRow="Eliminar"
              addRow="Agregar nuevo estudio"
              allowUpdating="Actualizar información"
            />
          </Editing>

          <Column dataField="Centros de Estudios" style={{ width: "100%" }}>
            <Validator>
              <RequiredRule />
            </Validator>
          </Column>
          <Column dataField="Nivel" caption="Nivel" style={{ width: "100%" }}>
            <RequiredRule />
            <Lookup
              dataSource={OpcionesNivel}
              valueExpr="ID"
              displayExpr="Name"
            />
          </Column>
          <Column
            dataField="Titulo obtenido"
            caption="Titulo"
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
          >
            <Validator>
              <RequiredRule />
            </Validator>
            <Lookup
              dataSource={OpcionesTitulo}
              valueExpr="ID"
              displayExpr="Name"
            />
          </Column>
          <Column dataField="Inicio" dataType="date" style={{ width: "100%" }}>
            <Validator>
              <RequiredRule />
            </Validator>
          </Column>
          <Column
            dataField="Finalización"
            dataType="date"
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
          >
            <Validator>
              <CompareRule
                message="Fecha fin es menor a fecha inicial"
                comparisonType={("Inicio", ">")}
              />
              <RequiredRule />
            </Validator>
          </Column>
        </DataGrid>
```

Can anybody help me with my issue?

Greeting!

Comment: I fixed my issue, I had to add the component, 'AsyncRule ' that validate my logic using the params.data (it´s an object that has the row value).

Answer (score 0):

```
<Column
            dataField="Finalización"
            dataType="date"
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
          >
            <RequiredRule />
            <AsyncRule
              message="Fecha de finalización debe de ser mayor a la inicio"
              validationCallback={this.asyncValidation}
            />
          </Column>
```

```
 asyncValidation(params) {
    return new Promise(function executor(resolve) {
      let compare1 = params.data["Inicio"];
      let compare2 = params.data["Finalización"];
      if (compare2 < compare1) {
        resolve(false);
      } else {
        resolve(true);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.